# WebLogic 12: websocket handshake excetion (500): The async-support is disabled

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, websocket, weblogic

The error is:

> org.springframework.web.socket.server.HandshakeFailureException: Error
>   during handshake: http://2.12.85.0:6/eto/tvoy; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The async-support is disabled on this
>   request: weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl

Server: WebLogic 12.
It's appears when i'm trying to connect to websocket.

My web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!--Позволяет работать с русскими символами-->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>AFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My webSocketConfig:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketHandlerRegistry;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
@EnableAsync
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("webSocketLogger");
    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        log.error("registerWebSocketHandlers");
        registry.addHandler(webSocketHandler(), "/chat").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandler webSocketHandler() {
        return new workspace.websocket.controller.WebSocketHandler();
    }

}
```

My websocket handler:

```
public class WebSocketHandler implements org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("webSocketLogger");

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession webSocketSession) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(WebSocketSession webSocketSession, WebSocketMessage<?> webSocketMessage) throws Exception {

    }


    @Override
    public void handleTransportError(WebSocketSession webSocketSession, Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
        log.error("transport error", throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession webSocketSession, CloseStatus closeStatus) throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsPartialMessages() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an application to use the asynchronous feature, the entire request processing chain must have the have this attribute set either through the annotation or in its deployment descriptor. An IllegalStateException will be thrown if an application tries to start an asynchronous operation and there is a servlet or servlet filter in the request processing chain that does not support asynchronous processing. So, to fix the issue, the set of filters had to be given an additional element:

```
<async-supported>true</async-supported>
```

In your web.xml you are missing this for encoding filter. So your encoding filter config should be like this:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>            
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>            
    </filter>
```

Comment: Thx! And this:
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        log.error("registerWebSocketHandlers");
        registry.addHandler(webSocketHandler(), "/chat")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .setHandshakeHandler(new DefaultHandshakeHandler(new WebLogicRequestUpgradeStrategy()))
                ;
    }